# PostgreSQL select value where '100%' using bigint

Tags: postgresql, sql, database, pgadmin-4

I am trying to select data from a bigint column in PgAdmin using SQL:

```
SELECT FROM public.addressbaseplus WHERE uprn LIKE '100%'
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT FROM public.addressbaseplus WHERE uprn LIKE '100%'
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 47
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and the error appears?

Comment: and, btw., `SELECT <nothing_here> FROM ...` selects no column...

Comment: @Hutch you should give DBeaver or DataGrip a try instead of PGAdmin4... a much better user experience for analysis.

Comment: Your title has '%100' and the question has '100%'. These are very different problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) keyword in SQL operates on strings not numeric datatypes like bigints. 
Presumably you want all the items where the uprn field begins '100'.

There are 2 approaches:

1. Select a range of values: `WHERE uprn < 200 AND uprn > 99`, but this won't find values like `1001`...
2. Cast the bigint to a string `WHERE uprn::text LIKE '100%'`

In the second case the `::` is syntax for a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).

It's worth noting that issues with SQL that don't specifically link to GIS issues are often better searched for on [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to compare a `BIGINT` column (`uprn`) with a *string matching sequence*, using the `LIKE` operator. That´s not going to work. You can cast the `uprn` column to text (`... WHERE uprn::text LIKE '100%'`) to filter with regex matching.

Doinig this with the used statement, however, will match all values starting with `100` and followed by any character (or none), e.g. `1001`, `10098274982374`, `100`; the `%` is a reserved wildcard for *anything*!

If you are looking for the string `"100%"` in a column (not your `BIGINT` column) you will have to escape the `"%"`, i.e. `... WHERE <tst_column> LIKE '100\%' ESCAPE '\';`